# Bluetooth won't detect devices 14.10

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-speaker

I have a Gateway NE-5224u. When I try to sync it with my bluetooth speakers, it doesn't detect them. Windows and android do.
Any ideas?
Any commands I should run in order to check how the bluetooth adapter is configured and working?

Thanks in advance!

---

After running this command

```
lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg | grep -i firmware
```

I get this result:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3f6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 04ca:300b Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1bcf:0007 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 28:E3:47:82:C1:E8  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:1842 acl:0 sco:0 events:112 errors:0
    TX bytes:3020 acl:0 sco:0 commands:112 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0xd8 0x7f 0x7b 0x8f
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'ubuntu-0'
    Class: 0x740100
    Service Classes: Rendering, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version:  (0x7)  Revision: 0x3101
    LMP Version:  (0x7)  Subversion: 0x1
    Manufacturer: Atheros Communications, Inc. (69)

[    0.294054] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.322350] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    1.322396] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    1.323672] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    1.323701] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
[    1.342813] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    3.444109] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 3 (with firmware version 0x254f00)
[   20.361568] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: No _BQC method, cannot determine initial brightness
```

---

This is the result for the commands Jeremy31 suggested:

```
pablo@pablo-gateway:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git linux-firmware
[sudo] password for pablo: 
formSorry, try again.
[sudo] password for pablo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version.
git is already the newest version.
linux-firmware is already the newest version.
linux-firmware set to manually installed.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  at binutils-dev cmake cmake-data comerr-dev dctrl-tools devscripts
  distro-info-data dput expect grive kde-l10n-engb krb5-multidev
  libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-filesystem1.54-dev
  libboost-program-options-dev libboost-program-options1.54-dev
  libboost-program-options1.54.0 libboost-system1.54-dev libboost-test-dev
  libboost-test1.54-dev libboost-test1.54.0 libboost1.54-dev
  libcommon-sense-perl libcurl4-openssl-dev libdistro-info-perl libexpat1-dev
  libexporter-lite-perl libgcrypt11-dev libgnutls-dev libgnutlsxx27
  libgpg-error-dev libgssrpc4 libidn11-dev libio-stringy-perl libjson-c-dev
  libjson-perl libjson-xs-perl libjson0-dev libkadm5clnt-mit9 libkadm5srv-mit9
  libkdb5-7 libkrb5-dev liblcms1 libldap2-dev libp11-kit-dev
  libparse-debcontrol-perl libquvi-0.9-0.9.3 libquvi-scripts-0.9 librtmp-dev
  libtar0 libtasn1-6-dev libtie-ixhash-perl libyajl-dev
  linux-headers-3.13.0-39 linux-headers-3.13.0-39-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-39-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-39-generic lua-bitop
  lua-expat lua-json lua-lpeg lua-socket python-pyinotify python3-magic
  streamer vlc-plugin-pulse xawtv-plugins
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
pablo@pablo-gateway:~$ git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-3.13.0-37.git
Cloning into 'bluetooth-3.13.0-37'...
remote: Counting objects: 47, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
remote: Total 47 (delta 9), reused 29 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (47/47), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
pablo@pablo-gateway:~$ cd bluetooth-3.13.0-37
pablo@pablo-gateway:~/bluetooth-3.13.0-37$ cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
pablo@pablo-gateway:~/bluetooth-3.13.0-37$ cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
pablo@pablo-gateway:~/bluetooth-3.13.0-37$ make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-48-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/pablo/bluetooth-3.13.0-37/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/home/pablo/bluetooth-3.13.0-37/Makefile'.  Stop.
make: *** [_module_/home/pablo/bluetooth-3.13.0-37] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-48-generic'
pablo@pablo-gateway:~/bluetooth-3.13.0-37$ sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo cp *.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
cp: cannot stat ‘*.ko’: No such file or directory
pablo@pablo-gateway:~/bluetooth-3.13.0-37$ echo btusb | sudo tee -a /etc/modulesbtusb
pablo@pablo-gateway:~/bluetooth-3.13.0-37$ echo ath3k | sudo tee -a /etc/modulesath3k
```

Comment: Can you add the results from these commands to your question `lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg | grep -i firmware`

Comment: Just added the results. Hope you can help, I don't have a clue of that  haha

Comment: I do and I can fix, just post the result of `uname -a` so I know what source code to use

Comment: Linux pablo-gateway 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

Actually this should work as there is another fix in the utopic kernel that helps atheros bluetooth

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Reboot and check `uname -a` if it isn't at least 3.16.0-32 do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and reboot

If you wish to keep your current kernel, then

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/76c9nfyeb01eki6/bluetooth-3.13-48.tar.gz
tar -zxf bluetooth-3.13-48.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo cp ath3k.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
```

Reboot and if you do updates and notice the bluetooth isn't working then

```
cd bluetooth
make clean
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo cp ath3k.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
```

And reboot.

If you notice that bluetooth isn't working after a cold start about 1/3 of the time, I would upgrade to the Utopic 3.13.0-32 or higher kernel as the fix is in there

EDIT: Found out why original answer didn't work as intended

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git linux-firmware
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-3.13.0-37.git
cd bluetooth-3.13.0-37/bluetooth
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo cp *.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
echo btusb | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
echo ath3k | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Originally had `cd bluetooth-3.13.0-37` and it needed to be `cd bluetooth-3.13.0-37/bluetooth`

Second edit: Now that you can discover devices you likely just need

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

You may have to unpair and redo the pairing sequence to get the audio to work

Comment: I got this error message:
pablo@pablo-gateway:~/bluetooth-3.13.0-37$ sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo cp *.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
cp: cannot stat ‘*.ko’: No such file or directory

Comment: There is a * in front of ko that might have been missed.  You can highlight commands and copy them with CTRL + c then click in terminal and paste with CTRL + ALT + v  `sudo cp *.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/`

Comment: Just added all results for the commands you gave me

Comment: I am going back to my old way of doing this without using github.  I will do a complete edit of the commands

Comment: could you find a way to solve this Jeremy? Thanks!

Comment: I changed answer, 2 methods, depends on whether you need to use the 3.13 kernel

Comment: Made progress. It find's devices now, but when I try to sync any, I get this error: Device added successfuly, but failed to connect. Any idea? Thanks man

Comment: When I run "pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover" I get this error message: Connection failure: Connection refused. Any idea Jeremy?